# Got probleme somewhere in my route. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Working in Laravel. 
I got a probleme out there. 
Error Message : Class 'Form' not found

My route :

```
Route::get('/h', function () {
return view('Account.hb');
});
Route::get('/h',['uses'=>'AccountController@manageCategory']);
Route::post('/h',['as'=>'add.category','uses'=>'AccountController@addCategory']);
```

In my template :

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'add.category']) !!}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Laravel does not come with any `Form` class or builder ... so not sure what you are referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added laravelcollective/html to your project? If not add it with this command:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

Then add this line to your config/app.php file in providers section:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

And add these lines to the same file in aliases section:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

For more information, visit [this link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html).

Answer (score 1):

New laravel doesnt have the package for Form Collective. So upon installing you can't do

> {!! Form::open(['route'=>'add.category']) !!}

If the project is existing and you running in local, make sure you run composer install to install dependency if ever it is included in composer package.

OR

you can just follow this steps in https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

and your good to go.